# Parallel.For loop not always exiting when done [intermittent error]

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, progress-bar, parallel.for

So I have a parallel for loop which works perfectly on its own. Basically it loops through a 32,000 item collection, and does some parsing and math and what not and outputs the expected result.

It takes long enough to warrant a loading bar so I made a new form and initialised it before this method is called and then simply add 1 to the progress bar after each loop is complete which works fine, it updates and all. Then after the loop is complete its *meant* load the next form for displaying the data and all is well.

Now the strange problem is that this method will always works perfectly when I remove the single line for updating the progress bar (near the end of the code), but when I leave it in, it will sometimes work as I want it, and sometimes it will do all the processing and will update the progress bar as normal and then gets to the end and just stop, it doesn't actually exit the loop and continue with the code (I can tell because the `Debug.WriteLine` just below it isn't triggered when it gets stuck). And I know the program isn't doing anything because the CPU is idling (where its at 100% when the loop is working) and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is the code I have:

```
public void ProcessData()
{
    try
    {               
        Globals.frmref.pgbProgress.Value = 0;
        string TimeZone = cmbTimeZone.Text;
        Globals.frmref.pgbProgress.Maximum = Globals.FileLength - 8;

        Parallel.For(0, Globals.FileLength - 9, i =>
        {
            Globals.data[i].TimeTemp = "{0}/{1}/20{2} {3}:{4}:{5}";

            //Process the time and date (received in utc as ddmmyy and HHmmss.fff) to dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss.fff
            Globals.data[i].TimeTemp = String.Format(Globals.data[i].TimeTemp, Globals.data[i].DateRAW.Substring(0, 2), Globals.data[i].DateRAW.Substring(2, 2), Globals.data[i].DateRAW.Substring(4, 2), Globals.data[i].Hours, Globals.data[i].Minutes, Globals.data[i].Seconds);
            Globals.data[i].Time = DateTime.Parse(Globals.data[i].TimeTemp.Split('.')[0], CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU"));
            Globals.data[i].Time = Globals.data[i].Time.AddMilliseconds(Double.Parse(Globals.data[i].TimeTemp.Split('.')[1]));
            if (TimeZone.Contains("-"))
            {
                Globals.data[i].Time = Globals.data[i].Time - TimeSpan.Parse(TimeZone.Substring(1, TimeZone.Length - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                Globals.data[i].Time = Globals.data[i].Time + TimeSpan.Parse(TimeZone.Substring(1, TimeZone.Length - 1));
            }

            //Process the lat and lon input to Decimal Degrees
            Globals.data[i].DDLat = Globals.data[i].LatDegrees + (Globals.data[i].LatMinutes / 60) + (Globals.data[i].LatSeconds / 3600);
            Globals.data[i].DDLon = Globals.data[i].LonDegrees + (Globals.data[i].LonMinutes / 60) + (Globals.data[i].LonSeconds / 3600);

            if (Globals.data[i].NS == 'S')                          //North/South designator
            {
            //Make the dd coord negative if its southern
            Globals.data[i].DDLat = Globals.data[i].DDLat * -1;
            }
            if (Globals.data[i].EW == 'W')                          //East/West Designator
            {
            //ditto
            Globals.data[i].DDLon = Globals.data[i].DDLon * -1;
            }
            //***This is the line breaks it sometimes***
            Globals.frmref.pgbProgress.Invoke(new Action(() => Globals.frmref.pgbProgress.Value++)); 
        });
        Debug.WriteLine("Made it");
        Globals.frmref.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred, email wmatt1672@gmail.com with details of the error.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

I've tried locking the `ProgressBar` control before its updated, using an `int` to store the value and then update the progress bar via another method, and using `Task.Factory` (which runs the code weirdly). I'm all out of ideas.

TL;DR: `Parallel.For` loop sometimes doesn't exit after it's complete only when I add the one line of code for adding `1` to a progress bar.

Comment: If it happens intermitient, hat is definetly a race condition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software Unfortunately they are the most notoriously hard to debug. The Progress report itself seems allright as you use invoke. So maybe it is someplace else? The JiT is good at cutting out dead code. And one of the first things it will clean up is code whose result is never actualyl outputted. Maybe the faulty code is entirely skipped when you do not Progress Report?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the observer and observable design pattern

Comment: What on earth is `Globals`? You're not using a static class to hold your variables are you?

Comment: @Enigmativity yea it’s just a small school program so i’m using some dodgy methods. But it’s worked well so far.

Comment: @NesanMano I’m not sure what that is, could you provide a link for some reading or something?

Comment: @Christopher yea I’ll look at JiT, but I can’t see why it would skip anything, all it’s doing it adding 1 to a progress bar and then looping again

Comment: Maybe it is your exception handling? That Excpetion handling is very odd. Normally you just let the exception go on/rethrow it, rather then calling Application.Exit(). Depending on wich kind of Exception you had, it might not even be possible to dispaly a message box anymore. I have two articles that I link often: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @MattWilson The observer design pattern is a software architecture. It is also a common solution you the problem your are dealing with. Basically, your progress bar will be the observer and you model will be the observable. Here is a link to how to implement de design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern